# Import/Export problem for .obj files in Blender 2.79

Tags: export, import, error

I'm using **Blender 2.79**. Importing and exporting .obj files worked fine. Then I uninstalled blender and reinstalled. Now I can't able to import/export .obj files. Then I tried back Blender 2.78c. No error popped up this time! -_- .

Can someone please explain?

**Error:**

[image: Error pop-up while importing .obj file]

Comment: Might be a bug in the newer version, hard to tell

Comment: You say you uninstalled and reinstalled blender. It looks like the uninstall didn't work and you managed to get duplicate copies of supporting files, notice at the top the first error is "already registered as a subclass." The last path in your error is your settings folder rather than in program files, you may have a manual install of an addon or scripts that is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem. It's caused by Widnows Defender Security Center.
I solved it by opening Security Center -> Apps & browser control -> Check apps and files set to **off**

Comment: Oh really? I tried another way and resolved. You will find a folder in the name of your Blender version in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\. Delete the folder and reinstall blender. Everything works fine then! This error is mostly caused if the folder is corrupted.